# Solve de equation: σ(∅(n))=2^n

Tags: totient-function, arithmetic-functions, multiplicative-function

Solve de equation: $$\sigma(\phi(n))=2^n$$

I got $$\sigma(n)={2^{n+1}}$$
Then, if $n=p^a$,
$$\sigma(n)=\frac{{p^{a+1}}-1}{p-1}={2^{n+1}}$$
Then I got stuck... I don't know how to find this prime, I tried for hours :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I finally find this equation can't be solve. The secret is not see $\sigma$ function as a fraction, but like the sum of the divisors. So $\sigma(n)<1+2+...+n=n(n+1)/2$, because de divisors of $n$ are included in the sum. But $n(n+1)/2<2^{n+1}$ for $n>0$.Then, there's no $n$ that is answer of the equation.